# angularjs and select2: not able to select option without $digest error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jquery-select2

I have a problem with a select2 select box (http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) in an angularjs project. If I try to select an option in the select box from javascript (I do this in a directive to update the UI when the model changes), I always get the error

Error: $digest already in progress

Although I get the error, the UI behaviour is correct. Afterwards, the right option in the select box is select. But, an error is thrown every time.

I created a little example on plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZLQPr3

I see the error in the firefox/firebug and chrome console on mac.

Comment: The best thing is Using angular UI  Instead of select2 .. You cannot able to Use Angular Dynamic Variable in Select 2 .

Comment: This would Serve your cause                              https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select   and this                                                                http://plnkr.co/edit/juqoNOt1z1Gb349XabQ2?p=preview Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

While this is not the best solution, you may want to try this

http://plnkr.co/edit/zidLr3?p=preview

AFAIK The problem is in the `trigger` that causes multiple `$digest`.

Comment: actually, it doesn't work. I didn't test properly. If the model changes in my use case, a wrong option is selected. Need to make further investigations ...